# Write to Jena RDF model through pagination

Tags: java, pagination, rdf, jena, outputstream

I intend to convert the data in an SQL database into an RDF dump. I have a model and an ontology defined.

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM, model);
```

The ontModel has many classes defined in it. Now let us suppose I have 10000 records in my SQL db and I want to load them into the model and write it into a file. However, I want to paginate in case of a memory overflow.

```
int fromIndex = 0;
int toIndex = 10;

while(true) {
     //1. get resources between fromIndex to toIndex from sql db
     // if no more resources 'break'
     //2. push these resources in model                   
     //3. write the model to a file
     RDFWriter writer = model.getWriter();
     File file = new File(file_path);
     FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
     writer.write(this.model, fileWriter, BASE_URL); 
     model.close();

     from = to+1;
     to = to+10;            

 }
```

Now, how does one append the new resources to the existing resources in the file. Because currently I see the ontology getting written twice and it throws an exception

> org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: The markup in the document
>   following the root element must be well-formed.

Is there a way to handle this already?

Answer (score 1):

> Now, how does one append the new resources to the existing resources
>   in the file. Because currently I see the ontology getting written
>   twice and it throws an exception

A model is a set of triples.  You can add more triples to the set, but that's not quite the same thing as "appending", since a model doesn't contain duplicate triples, and sets don't have a specified order, so "appending" isn't quite the right metaphor.

Jena can handle pretty big models, so you might first see whether you can just create the model and add everything to it, and then write the model to the file.  While it's good to be cautious, it's not a bad idea to see whether you can do what you want without jumping through hoops.

If you do have problems with in-memory models, you might consider using a TDB backed model which will use disk for storage.  You could do incremental updates to that model using the model API, or SPARQL queries, and then extract the model afterward in some serialization.

One more option, and this is probably the easiest if you really do want to append to a file, is to use a non-XML serialization of the RDF, such as Turtle or N-Triples.  These are text based (N-Triples is line-based), so appending new content to a file is not a problem.  This approach is described in the answer to [Adding more individuals to existing RDF ontology](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19537789/1281433).